# Disable ng-class update on scroll event

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-digest

I try to disable ng-class reevulating at each scroll event.
It is especially painful, as I try to implement an addressbook, where each alphabet is checked via ng-class if it is active or not:

```
<div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active: alphabetIsActive(a)}" ng-repeat-start="a in alphabet" ng-repeat-end>{{a}}</a>
    </div>
```

where alphabet is:

```
  $scope.alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUXYZ'.split('');
```

and alphabetIsActive:

```
$scope.alphabetIsActive = function(letter) {
  console.log('alphabetIsActive: ' + letter);
  if (letter === 'C') {return true;}
  else {return false;}
};
```

Reevulating the above piece of code at each scroll event is crazy, and it has a noticable lag even on a desktop computer.

I'm aware of the `ng-class="::{active: alphabetIsActive(a)}"` form, but it kills interactivity completely, ng-class will never update. (not even on a click event).

In my case I only need reevulating the selected alphabet, when a list (`$scope.mainList` variable) changes.

Comment: If you removed the console.log(), and just had `return letter == 'C'`, it would already be faster. Why is this reevaluated at each scroll event? It shouldn't be. I doubt this extremely simple and fast code actually causes a performance problem.

Comment: `console.log` was there to prove the many executions. Still, even if I remove, the original question is still valid: how to disable ng-class being reevaluated at each scroll event?

Comment: As I said, it shouldn't be. And it's not, unless some code of your causes that. But you didn't post it. Here's a plunkr reusing your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/gANc9EoC0EMMbgPnWVTM?p=preview. Open your console and scroll. Nothing is printed when scrolling. If you want help, post code demonstrating the problem.